# How to render localized content pages with ServiceStack Razor?

Tags: razor, servicestack

I need to have separate default.cshtml for each culture. For example, default.en.cshtml, default.dk.cshtml and so on. Correct content page should be selected in depends on current request culture.

What is the best approach to implement that with ServiceStack? An IVirtualPathProvider implementation?

**SOLVED!** Works for me:

```
Plugins.Add(new CultureAwareRazorFormat())
```

was added to the AppHost.

Related stuff:

```
public class CultureAwareRazorFormat : RazorFormat
{
    public override ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver CreatePageResolver()
    {
        return base.CreatePageResolver();
    }

    public override ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager CreateViewManager()
    {
        return new CultureAwareRazorViewManager(this, VirtualPathProvider);
    }
}


public class CultureAwareRazorViewManager : RazorViewManager
{
    public CultureAwareRazorViewManager(IRazorConfig viewConfig, IVirtualPathProvider virtualPathProvider) : base(viewConfig, virtualPathProvider)
    {

    }

    public override RazorPage GetPage(string absolutePath)
    {
        var extension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(absolutePath);
        if (extension != null)
        {
            string path = absolutePath.Remove(absolutePath.IndexOf(extension, System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
            var localizedPage = TryGetLocalizedPage(path, extension, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
            if (localizedPage != null) return localizedPage;
        }

        return base.GetPage(absolutePath);
    }

    private RazorPage TryGetLocalizedPage(string path, string extension, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = base.GetPage(path + "." + culture.ToString().ToLower() + extension);
        if (result != null) return result;

        result = base.GetPage(path + "." + culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + extension);
        if (result != null) return result;

        result = base.GetPage(path + "." + culture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName + extension);
        if (result != null) return result;

        return null;
    }

}
```